# Redirect wordpress URLs containing specific word

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a very specific issue. I want to auto redirect

https://example.com/who-you-are-lyrics/ to
https://example.com/who-you-are/

I have removed the word -lyrics from about 10 000 records in the database, but the problem is that these urls are indexed by Google. So I need to auto redirect the URL containing -lyrics to the url without -lyrics.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you seeking an `.htaccess` solution?  If so, please confirm that `RedirectMatch ^(.*?)-lyrics/(.*)$ $1/$2` works before I post an answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RedirectMatch ^(.*?)-lyrics/(.*)$ $1/$2
```

This will only make replacements when there is a match, and the result will exclude the `-lyrics` substring.